# Can I do a dry run of Update-Database in EF 6?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am wondering if there is a way to run `Update-Database` from the Package Manager Console with something similar to the Rails `--dry-run` flag, in order to see what will be run before doing it.  My googling has led to no corresponding command for EF.

Is there one?  Is there a hack to do essentially the same thing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `Update-Database` with a `-Script` flag to generate a SQL script instead of applying the migration. If you don't specify a source migration, it will use the current database state as the starting point, so you can use the file to verify what would have been executed on the database.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#script

Comment: It's `Update-Database -Script` with one dash, not two.